# Insert values to excel cells vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, insert

One cell (1,1) contains the number, 202205252027. And now I will cut this value to another cell (2,2) and add a "-" sign in the mid of the value like 202-20-52520-27. Below is my code.

```
Dim xsh As excel.sheets(1)
Dim oldCell As String = ""
Dim newCell As String = ""
oldCell = Trim$(xsh.Cells(1,1).Value)
newCell = oldCell.Insert(3, "-")
newCell = newCell.Insert(6, "-")
newCell = newCell.Insert(12, "-")
xsh.Cells(2,2).Value = newCell
```

The problem is I get an error, "Specified Argument was out of the range of valid values" when I want to insert the first "-".
Can you guys give me an idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you need to be more specific with setting the variables? what sheet is xsh?

Comment: Is insert into string an actual excel function, I have seen udf's.

Comment: Sorry, Davesexcel. I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: the sheet I know it's no problem, it's just I didn't remember what exactly I type.

Comment: Start with the Debugger and inspect the value of oldCell before trying to modify it's content.  Suspect the length would be < 3 at some point which will cause the exception

Answer (score 0):

Did you use loop or condition? the code doesn't have any problems.
If you use loop, have you checked your last cell? If it doesn't contain 12 character, then you cannot proceed further and then get this error.
Check carefully. If the comment helps you, please tick.